# Laravel 5: Route binding returns empty object

Tags: object, laravel, binding, model, routes

I'm trying to get the binding to work (following a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2IWdRVEheo) on youtube). At this point, I am basically copy-pasting the code; still, it does not seem to work.

Here's the routes.php:

```
Route::model('song', 'App\Song');

Route::get('songs', 'SongsController@index');
Route::get('songs/{slug}', 'SongsController@show');
Route::get('songs/{slug}/edit', 'SongsController@edit');
Route::patch('songs/{slug}', 'SongsController@update');
```

Song.php:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Song extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'lyrics'
    ];
}
```

And SongsController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Song;

class SongsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Song $song) {

        $songs = $song->get();

        return view('songs.index', compact('songs'));
    }

    public function show(Song $song) {

        return view('songs.show', compact('song'));
    }

    public function edit($slug) {

        $song = Song::whereSlug($slug)->first();
        return view('songs.edit', compact('song'));
    }

    public function update($slug, Request $request) {

        $song = Song::whereSlug($slug)->first();
        $song->fill($request->input())->save();

        return redirect('songs');
    }
}
```

I've deliberately left the `$slug` instead of `Song $song` in `edit` and `update`, since this is where the problem is.
If I understand this correctly, I should be able to access the $song object in all 4 methods (given that the first parameter is `Song $song` in all of them); however, only in the case of the `index` method am I able to obtain anything from the database. The others just give me an (sort of) empty object. Here's a `dd($song)` called in the `show` function (the URI being `http://localhost:8000/songs/boyfriend` or `http://localhost:8000/songs/1` - both cause the same output regardless of using `Route::bind` instead of `Route::model`, as described below):

```
Song {#144 ▼
  #fillable: array:2 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #casts: []
  #touches: []
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: false
}
```

The entry in the database exists; tinker:

```
>>> App\Song::whereSlug('boyfriend')->first();
=> <App\Song #000000005ba18d590000000003230878> {
       id: 1,
       title: "Boyfriend",
(...)
```

The methods `edit` and `update` work flawlessly (unless I try removing `$slug` and putting in `Song $song` as the first parameter).

I have tried [updating the $compiledPath](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0.16), `clear-compiled`, `cache:clear`, restarted everything a billion times; I have also tried replacing the `Route::model` line with

```
Route::bind('song', function($slug) {

    return App\Song::whereSlug($slug)->first();
});
```

in the `routes.php` file (and the same thing using the `$router->bind` syntax). I am using XAMPP with PHP 5.6.8 with the project started through `php artisan serve`, and the `php artisan --version` is  `Laravel Framework version 5.1.2 (LTS)`.

I tried dd($slug) in the Route::bind - it does nothing (as if it weren't there), same with both `findOrFail` and `firstOrFail`; however, putting `blah!` before `return` causes a `FatalErrorException`, so the function does seem to get called. What am I missing here?

Is this a bug? Should this be working correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're binding to `song` but in your `routes.php` you have the placeholder as `slug`. You need to change it to `song`

```
Route::get('songs', 'SongsController@index');
Route::get('songs/{song}', 'SongsController@show');
Route::get('songs/{song}/edit', 'SongsController@edit');
Route::patch('songs/{song}', 'SongsController@update');
```

Comment: That worked, thank you - I was just about to shoot myself in the face. Thanks again!

Comment: So simple, yet so easy to overlook.  I got caught on this having {itemId} and using $item in the method.  Thanks for this.